# Beef from cows?

Tags: meat, animals

[Rabbi Sholem Fishbane, Kashruth Administrator at the Chicago Rabbinical Council, says:](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CuU03gH-DNs#t=436s)

> You would think, with so many cow *sh'chita*s in America, with so many, you know, steaks, what we have, that there would be [udders easy to find], but doesn't — no one seemed to be doing [*sh'chita* on] milch cows.

It sounds as though he means a lot of kosher beef in America is from cows (female animals)<sup>[1]</sup> — just not from, as he puts it, "milch cows", cows that are bred for milk (or that are nursing).

Is it possible that that's what he means? In other words, is there in fact a lot of kosher beef in America from cows? I ask because I've always understood that kosher beef in America is from male animals exclusively or almost exclusively.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> which is why he'd expect udders easy to find

Comment: I would think that your gut instinct would have to be correct. For breeding you need only a very low bull to cow ratio. For milk production you obviously need a lot of milk producing cows. He was probably speaking casually and said cows when he really meant cattle. But I have no actual information to backup my assumptions.

Comment: See the answer below that it is specifically milk cows (not female cows in general) that are not shechted because they are almost always treifas.

Answer (score 6):

Speaking from Slaughterhouse experience.

The cows that are slaughtered are usually 12-24 months and have not become pregnant.

Female cattle are usually slaughtered as bulls are more valuable for obvious reasons. V"dal.

I saw on one occasion a pregnant behemah shechted and when they opened her up it was a ready to be born baby calf. The halchas on this are interesting but for another topic. Kitzur: The calf doesnt need to be shechted.

In the USA a calf in this situation is thrown down the chute with other refuse. In Israel I have heard that the calf is taken out and brought to the farm to live.

Answer (score 4):

We no longer shecht dairy cows, since most of them turn out to be treifas, as R. Schachter explained in a YU Audio shiur, which I have partly transcribed below.

R. Hershel Schachter
Nov 22, 2008
"Kashrus in the Home"
http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/729136/Rabbi_Hershel_Schachter/Kashrus_in_the_Home

"Dairy cows have a very high incidence of treifos -- it's taka a
question how  we're still allowed to drink the milk if there's such a
high incidence of treifos....In America they milk the cow 3 times a
day, which is abnormal -- years ago they never did that, and because
they milk them for all they're worth, that's why they develop the
sicknesses, and then when they are not producing enough milk, they
kill them; and these dairy cows don't taste so good -- the fleish
doesn't taste so good -- so usually in the industry they use this
flesh to make hotdogs or salami, since with hotdogs or salami you put
in so many spices, you don't taste the flavor of the fleish anyway;
this fleish has a funny taste -- it doesn't taste bad, but it has an
irregular taste...They told me that years ago they used to schecht
these dairy cows and in America they found 80% incidence of treifos
and in South Africa when they schechted the cows they had 95%
incidence of sirchos (scabs) on the lungs..."

He then goes on to explain that, based on this, the milk should also be non-kosher, if we know that the cows are non-kosher, and that he is not sure how we are allowed to drink milk nowadays.

Comment: I wonder if the same holds true for Cholov Yisroel or if we can expect that those animals are treated in accordance with tzaar baalei chaim.

Comment: @yoel I am not aware that it is possible to check if a behemah is truly treif without opening it up which would then render it treif. Isn't there a concept that something is kosher right up until it is proven not? ie: Tefillin checking (at least the Rambams opinion.) This is how commerical dairies are run. Milk them, replace them, and get ride of the useless ones. Source: My friend was head mashgiach for the Cholav Yisroel Dairy in upstate New York for 3 years.

Comment: @yoel: There is no difference for cholov yisroel farms -- those cows are mostly treifas too. R. Schachter does not consume any dairy at all based on his concerns, although most people are lenient that there is a chazakah that any particular animal is kosher until it is established otherwise.

Comment: @Curiouser R' Schachter's opinion is based on chumra.  R' Belsky disagree's with R' Schachter's stance. "Most cows on C.Y. or non C.Y. farms are treifas" is a gross over generalization. This is bottom line halacha. Anything above it is chumra. Dont make Klal Yisroel makel because you chose to be machmir. Most cows rendered treif in a slaughterhouse are not even 100% but have sufek and better not to eat them. So using them in statistics doesnt work. R' Z.M. Goldberg of Jerusalem also disagrees with this stance. Its just like everything in kashrus these days. Politics.

Comment: @ mochin: R. Schachter's opinion is based on the 95% treifa rate in South Africa, as noted in his shiur. Based on this, he does not understand why the milk is kosher. In his view this is not merely a chumra. Of course others disagree; as I noted most people still drink milk. I am not trying to impugn anyone, despite your accusation.

Comment: @curiouser Please be more specific. "Those cows are mostely treifas too" Where? S.A. what about Israel and America where 99% of Jews live. Lets be clear. "Most people are lenient" No, Most people follow halacha and are most likely machmir then the halacha and dont realize it. This is assumed we are talking about Chalov Yisroel. If we are talking about Non C.Y. then this is a whole other discussion. If you are trying not to impugn anyone, take care of your words as to label thousands of Jews are eating or drinking non kosher food/drink. R"L.

Comment: @ mochin: Please calm down. R. Schachter noted that 80% of milk cows in AMERICA were found to be treifas. Hence he is cautious not to consume dairy, since he feels that the halacha does not allow consuming milk from a cow which is almost certain to be found to be non-kosher. Now, many other poskim take a different (lenient) approach, where the word lenient means that they allow the milk even in this case of suspicion, because there is no proof that the cow is non-kosher until it is shechted. I have no idea what cholov yisroel has to do with this question.

Comment: Despite your insistence, I am not labeling any Jews as sinning, God forbid. I am just trying to explain that there is a disagreement among the poskim, and some poskim are strict and some are lenient. (As with all issues, no news here). No pejorative sense is meant with my word choice. Please take care of your thoughts so as not to construe another's writing to mean something critical when you could interpret it as simply being descriptive.

Comment: paraphrasing from your quote - they milk them dry and then kill em.  So it is entirely feasible, even according to your stats, that when they are producing milk they are kosher, but when shechted they are treif.